# Nesting Indirect function in Max array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect, maxifs

I have a cell that is supposed to scan a range for a name, and then return the max (most recent) date from another range.  Essentially I'm making a last date contacted cell for case managers.  I had it all worked out but because I was using direct cell references, everything got messed up when I sorted the rows.

This is the closest I could get to an INDIRECT array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(Encounters!A$3:A$1000 = INDIRECT("Caselist"&"!"&"B"&ROW()), Encounters!C$3:C$1000))
```

A little help with syntax would be much appreciated.  If I type

```
=INDIRECT("Caselist"&"!"&"B"&ROW())
```

into another cell it returns the value I'm looking for.

Comment: Why do you need INDIRECT? Why doesn't `=MAX(IF(Encounters!A$3:A$1000 = Caselist!B3, Encounters!C$3:C$1000))` work for you? Substitute whatever row you are currently on for the 3 in B3.

Comment: Because if I use a direct cell reference, like B3, the formula falls apart after I sort the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the volatile INDIRECT whenever possible. In most cases, the non-volatile INDEX can be used.

```
=MAX(IF(Encounters!A$3:A$1000 = INDEX(Caselist!B:B, ROW()), Encounters!C$3:C$1000))
```

This is an **array formula** and requires CSE.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect.